# HUD keeps flickering

Tags: unity, hud

I just switched to ubuntu and I have encountered an error where **if I reboot my system the second time I do that my unity will just keep flickering like it is reloading.** I do want to point out that I was using windows before doing this installation but I have used ubuntu before on this computer and I didn't have this problem and **neither a clean installation solved the problem**.Any help would be greatly appreciated.
**Graphics:** Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller

Comment: Sounds like a graphics driver issue. What graphics card are you using and what driver?

Comment: @Stormlord Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller

Comment: Can someone please help me, i will give any information you need plss!!